# Flutter Material Icons rendering random icons on web

Tags: flutter, web, dart, flutter-web

So in my flutter app, the material icons show properly in native, but in web, all have a different icon. What should or can I do with it?

[image: Here is how it looks in web]

[image: Here it is working on native android]

Comment: did you end up solving it? I have the same issue

Comment: I ended up solving it, delete the fontmanifest.xml in your web build folder and then compile your app again

Comment: I realized it doesn't happen in --release mode. only in debug.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a cache problem which can either be solved by running `flutter pub cache repair` or running `flutter clean` between every step of changing a channel and upgrading it.